# Apache: Changing path to httpd.conf

Tags: apache

A few months ago I installed Apache on Mac OSX 10.6.8.  Apache automatically installed at /usr/local/apache2.  After some hiccups I successfully got Apache to listen on port 8080, and I was able to get Apache to execute cgi scripts out of /usr/local/apache2/cgi-bin.

I haven't used apache since then, and when I recently fired up apache using:

```
/usr/local/apache2/bin$ sudo apachectl -k start
```

and then entered the following url in my browser:

```
http://localhost:8080
```

apache wouldn't serve up the index.html page or any other page in /usr/local/apache2/htdocs.  However, if I used the url:

```
http://localhost
```

then apache did serve up "an index.html" page that displayed, "It works".  I checked my httpd.conf file located at /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf, and apache was set to listen on port 8080:

```
Listen 8080
```

Next, I changed the file /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/index.html to display, "Hello world", but apache still served up a page that said "It works" when I used the url:

```
http://localhost
```

I checked my httpd.conf file again for this line:

```
DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs"
```

So I concluded that my apache install was not using the httpd.conf file located at /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf.  I did some searching with google, and I found this command:

```
/usr/local/apache2/bin$ apachectl -V
```

which produced the output:

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Unix)
Server built:   Jul 12 2012 15:09:37
Server's Module Magic Number: 20051115:30
Server loaded:  APR 1.3.8, APR-Util 1.3.9
Compiled using: APR 1.3.8, APR-Util 1.3.9
Architecture:   64-bit
Server MPM:     Prefork
  threaded:     no
    forked:     yes (variable process count)
Server compiled with....
 -D APACHE_MPM_DIR="server/mpm/prefork"
 -D APR_HAS_SENDFILE
 -D APR_HAS_MMAP
 -D APR_HAVE_IPV6 (IPv4-mapped addresses enabled)
 -D APR_USE_FLOCK_SERIALIZE
 -D APR_USE_PTHREAD_SERIALIZE
 -D SINGLE_LISTEN_UNSERIALIZED_ACCEPT
 -D APR_HAS_OTHER_CHILD
 -D AP_HAVE_RELIABLE_PIPED_LOGS
 -D DYNAMIC_MODULE_LIMIT=128
 -D HTTPD_ROOT="/usr"
 -D SUEXEC_BIN="/usr/bin/suexec"
 -D DEFAULT_PIDLOG="/private/var/run/httpd.pid"
 -D DEFAULT_SCOREBOARD="logs/apache_runtime_status"
 -D DEFAULT_LOCKFILE="/private/var/run/accept.lock"
 -D DEFAULT_ERRORLOG="logs/error_log"
 -D AP_TYPES_CONFIG_FILE="/private/etc/apache2/mime.types"
 -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE="/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf"
```

The httpd.conf my apache install is now using is located at /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf, which contains these lines:

```
ServerRoot "/usr"

Listen 80

DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
```

My question is: how in the hell did those changes occur?  The apache docs say that the path to httpd.conf is set at compile time.  I considered the possibility that /usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl might be sym linked to the system apache, but this output:

```
/usr/local/apache2/bin$ ls -al
total 2104
drwxr-xr-x  20 root   admin     680 Feb 19 12:36 .
drwxr-xr-x  15 root   admin     510 Feb 19 12:36 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root   admin   57200 Feb 19 12:36 ab
-rwxr-xr-x   1 7stud  staff    3410 Feb 19 12:32 apachectl
```

doesn't indicate that is the case.

Comment: Try `which apachectl` at the command prompt.

Comment: ~$ which apachectl  => 
/usr/sbin/apachectl.  So a path problem?

Comment: Then you're running the system apachectl, not your own one in `/usr/local/apache2/bin`.

Comment: Alright!  Thanks. /usr/local/apache2/bin$ sudo ./apachectl -k start.  If you put your post in an answer, I'll give you some points.  Thanks again.

Comment: Dear moderators, the FAQ says this: "if your question generally covers …

software tools commonly used by programmers

… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"  Apache is a commonly used software tool use by php, perl, ruby, and python programmers for local web development.  You all are violating stackoverflow's terms of service by closing this thread.  In any case, you are too late.  Ha ha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`which` shows that you're running the system `apachectl` instead of your custom one. Try

```
sudo /usr/local/apache2/bin/apachectl -k start
```

...to run yours and start your own custom apache.

Comment: Thanks for wading into an apache configuration question.  You are a brave man.  ++